# looking for malloc in shared library

Tags: c++, linux, malloc

I have been trying to find references to `malloc` in a shared library, but I got results which I don't fully understand. I have two libraries which are pretty similar, in one of them I see malloc referenced:

```
readelf -Ws mylib.so | grep malloc
   72: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
53916: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc
```

The other doesn't have it, all good so far. But if I compile with debug symbols and do `readelf --debug-dump=info`, I see `malloc` being referenced all over the place in both libs:

```
<1><31f72b>: Abbrev Number: 222 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
   <31f72d>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2236cc4): malloc
   <31f731>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 319
   <31f733>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 539
   <31f735>   DW_AT_type        : <0x70ad>
   <31f739>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
   <31f739>   DW_AT_external    : 1
```

How to interpret this, is the lib statically linked against glibc?

Another question: any suggestion on a good way to trace heap allocations? They don't have to be done via `malloc` I guess?

Comment: If the only reason for you to do this is heap allocation tracking, you may look at runtime analysis programs like e.g. `valgrind`.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about finding references to `malloc` in shared libraries, but the problem to which you believe the solution involves finding references to `malloc`, so that's what you're asking about. Your reference to "trace heap allocations" indicates that you have a different, real problem involving memory allocations. To trace memory leaks, on Linux there's a very useful `valgrind` tool.

Comment: I guess I should have foreseen that using the word "trace" will make people think I have problems with memory leaks and stuff :D What I want to do is to find all places where heap memory can be allocated in my library :)